# Eclipse: TAB-key not working correctly in PHP editor (PDT)

Tags: php, eclipse, editor, tabs

in the latest version of Eclipse (Helios) the tab-settings seem to have changed.

When I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> the cursor ALWAYS moves 2 spaces, no matter where it is.  Depending on the position of the cursor it should move to the next multiple of 2.

I have set it up like this:

```
Displayed tab width    :  2
Insert spaces for tabs : checked
Formatter - tab policy : spaces  (2)
```

Has anybody else got this working in Helios ?
Do I have a setting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the weird tab behaviour you describe since Helios (I think).

Plus -- tabbing inside a comment block or anywhere *part way though a line* inserts a tab rather than spaces too. Very frustrating.

This is a bug reported here -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326250

And there's a dropin that fixes it (for me anyway) here -- http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/downloads/50605/jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.ui.tabhandler_1.2.0.201101152009.jar/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this behavior was only happening in my mixed HTML/PHP files. Window->Preferences->Web and I adjusted Editor settings for both HTML Files and CSS Files to "Indent using spaces". Took a minute to clean up the existing files but seems to work how I prefer now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the support site for Eclipse and/or the PDT plugin?  It might be a known issue or there might be an update available.